Importxml errors with /div and [2] [3]
Importing using importxml code:
=LET(list, IMPORTXML("https://www.officialcharts.com/charts/dance-singles-chart/20240212/104/", "//*[@id='__nuxt']/div[3]/div/main/div[2]/section/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/p/a/span"), WRAPROWS(BYROW(list, LAMBDA(r, JOIN("", r))), 2))

The errors are to do with pulling unwanted text from column 1 chart positions NEW and Re get pulled in and causes table data to jump out of line. In different cells.
Could be to do with /div [2] [3]
Changing the /div and numbers

Exact copy of ImportXML errors in /div or 2 3. See Be Forthright When Cross Posting To Other Sites.

try:
=WRAPROWS(QUERY(TOCOL(IMPORTXML(
 "https://www.officialcharts.com/charts/dance-singles-chart/20240212/104/", 
 "//*[@id='__nuxt']//*/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/p/a"), 1), 
 "where not Col1 matches 'New|RE'", ), 2)


or:
=LET(list, IMPORTXML("https://www.officialcharts.com/charts/dance-singles-chart/20240212/104/", 
 "//*[@id='__nuxt']/div[3]/div/main/div[2]/section/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/p/a/span"), 
 WRAPROWS(QUERY(BYROW(list, LAMBDA(r, JOIN(, r))), "where not Col1 matches '^(RE|New)$'", ), 2))




You may try:
=let(Σ,tocol(importxml("https://www.officialcharts.com/charts/dance-singles-chart/20240209/104/","//*[@id='__nuxt']/div[3]/div/main/div[2]/section/div/div/div/div/div/div/p/a"),1),
 wraprows(filter(Σ,Σ<>"New",Σ<>"RE"),2))



So adding a filter Re and New removes the offending text. Thank you. Notice other approaches and variations to this. Amazed!
